# Get current authenticated Username via Azure Function on Node.js

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

What would be the best approach to retrieve O365/AzureAD user's details such as username who consumes an Azure Function on Node?

Only Online authenticated users are allowed to consume the Azure Function

All the examples I see are related to Azure Functions on C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Azure AD and node.js, the easiest way is to look at the X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME HTTP request header. Here is my test code for your reference.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)+". CurrentUser:"+req.headers['x-ms-client-principal-name']
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};
```

[image]

Reference:

[Advanced usage of authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims)

Comment: That's a great response, it does work. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: One more thing, anything to consider before enabling the authentication if I want to debug the function on my local build (locally via Visual code)?