# From Azure Function (secured by AAD), how to properly detect the caller (the end-user of SPFx WebPart) through the AadHttpClient?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, spfx, aadhttpclient

***Note:**
Both Azure Function and the SPFx WebPart mentioned below are written in **NodeJS/JavaScript**. None of them are in C#.*

I have an Azure Function (secured by AAD: App Registration) which is being called by `AadHttpClient` via SPFx WebPart on a SharePoint page. The SPFx codes look like this:

```
return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void, reject: (error: any) => void): void => {
    this.context.aadHttpClientFactory.getClient("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX") // <--- This is the AAD Client App Id.
    .then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
        
        client.post("https://myAzureFunctionName.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1", AadHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: someData
            })
        })
        .then((res: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((response: any): void => {
            console.log("SUCCESSFUL API RESPONSE:", response); // <--- At this point, I get the respond back from the Azure Function, successfully.
            resolve();
        }, (err: any): void => {
            console.error(err);
        });

    }, err => reject(err));
});
```

It is working fine **except** from the Azure Function end, I don't know how to properly detect who/which current **SharePoint User** is calling this API. The only dirty trick I can use is, of course, to attach the User Information, such as *Email Address*, (retrieved from [_spPageContextInfo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-get-user-properties-and-user-information-list) object) into the `AadHttpClient` API call, to the Azure Function.

### Question

- What is the proper/authentic way in which I can detect the caller (the currently logged in, end-user of SPFx WebPart) through the AadHttpClient, from the Azure Function end? So that I can use the user's Email Address further in the Azure Function.

Appreciate the helps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current user details from request header properties:

- User ID: X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID
- User Name: X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME
- Claims: X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL
- Identity Provider's ID: X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-IDP

**Source**: [From Azure Function (secured by AAD), how to properly detect the caller (the end-user of SPFx WebPart) through the AadHttpClient?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304011/from-azure-function-secured-by-aad-how-to-properly-detect-the-caller-the-end)

Comment: This is useful only if integrated AAD authentication is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
[How to get current user identity in Azure Function with Azure Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587136/how-to-get-current-user-identity-in-azure-function-with-azure-authentication)
To get current user info.
You can also decode access token You provided to the azure function with this code

```
var token = "[encoded jwt]";  
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks much for helping out. Unfortunately I forgot to mentioned that I didn't use C# solutions as I'm not fluent in C#. Both of my Azure Function and SPFx WebPart are written in NodeJS/JavaScript. And after studying the link you shared, I don't think "ClaimsPrincipal" Class is available in non-C# languages.

Comment: In that case You can check if there is x-ms-client-principal-name header present in the request (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292572/get-current-authenticated-username-via-azure-function-on-node-js) or get the bearer from Authorization header and decode it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript-without-using-a-library) 
User id is present in every jwt token

Answer (score 0):

As @marcin-wojciechowski suggests, **you can decode the JWT token attached within the Authorization header and read its claims**.

Here is some sample code:

```js
const jwt_decode = require("jwt-decode");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    const { headers } = req;
    const { authorization } = headers;

    const token = authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    //  returning the user object id
    context.res = {
        body: JSON.stringify(decoded.oid)
    };
}
```